# Creating a whole number with percentage calculator

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to use the percentage calculator (code below) but I only want it to out put whole numbers (rounded up where possible) as you cant have .3 of a business lead.

I have the code working so that it calculates and functions as intended but just need to reduce it to 0 decimal spaces.

I am building this onto wordpress but am happy to use a plugin or alternatively a 3rd party script if needed to solve this issue.

```
 <style>
    .entry-title {
    display: none;
    }
    .calculator {
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    }
    .calculator-banner {
    padding: 100px 0px;
    }
    .calculator-banner h1 {
        font-size: 55px;
        font-weight: 300;
        color: #4d4d4e;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .calculator-banner p {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 25px;
        color: #4d4d4e;
        padding: 0px;
        font-weight: 100;
        line-height: normal;
        max-width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .calculator .col-sm-4:first-child {
            border-right: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
    }
    .calculator .row:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f0f0f0;
    }
    
    .calculator .col-sm-4 p {
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
    .calculator p {
    padding: 10px;
    }
    input {
    background: none;
    margin: 10px;
    }
    </style>
    <div class="calculator-banner">
    <div class="container">
    <h1>Conversion <strong>Calculator</strong></h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin at dui eleifend neque ullamcorper mattis sed sed risus.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="calculator">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h5>Without Software</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h5>With Software</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <p>Website Visitors Per Month</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="number" name="price" id="websitevisitors-without" value="10000" onchange="myChangeFunction(this)" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="number" name="price" id="websitevisitors-with" value="10000" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <p>Standard Form Fill Conversion </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="number" name="qty" id="standard-form-fill-without" value="2"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="number" name="qty" id="standard-form-fill-with" value="2"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <p>Number of Form Fill Enquiries</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="number" name="total" id="number-of-form-fills-without" value="200" readonly />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="number" name="total" id="number-of-form-fills-with" value="200" readonly />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <p>Conversion from Identified Website Visitors</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <p>Number of Website Visitor Conversions</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <p>Total Number of Opportunities</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="number" name="total" id="total-opportunities-without" value="200" readonly />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="number" name="total" id="total-opportunities-with" value="200" readonly />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <p>Conversion of Opportunities to Sales</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="number" name="total" id="conversion-of-opportunities-without" value="20" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="number" name="total" id="conversion-of-opportunities-with" value="20" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <p>Number of Sales</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="number" name="total" id="number-of-sales-without" value="40" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="number" name="total" id="number-of-sales-with" value="40" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <p>Average Order Value</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="number" name="total" id="average-order-value-without" value="1000" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="number" name="total" id="average-order-value-with" value="1000" />
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <p>Revenue Generated</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="number" name="total" id="revenue-generated-without" value="40000" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="number" name="total" id="revenue-generated-with" value="40000" />
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <p>12month business benefit</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="number" name="total" id="year-business-benefit-without" value="480000" step="0.01"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="number" name="total" id="year-business-benefit-with" value="480000" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $('#websitevisitors-without, #standard-form-fill-without, #conversion-of-opportunities-without, #number-of-sales-without, #average-order-value-without, #year-business-benefit-without, #revenue-generated-without').change(function() {
            var webvisitorswithout = parseFloat($('#websitevisitors-without').val()).toFixed(2);
            var standardformfillwithout = parseFloat($('#standard-form-fill-without').val()).toFixed(2);
            var converstionofopportunitieswihtout = parseFloat($('#conversion-of-opportunities-without').val()).toFixed(2);
            var numberofsaleswithout = parseFloat($('#number-of-sales-without').val()).toFixed(2);
            var averageordervaluewithout = parseFloat($('#average-order-value-without').val()).toFixed(2);
            var yearbusinessbenefitwithout = parseFloat($('#year-business-benefit-without').val()).toFixed(2);
            var revenuegeneratedwithout = parseFloat($('#revenue-generated-without').val()).toFixed(2);
    
            $('#number-of-form-fills-without, #total-opportunities-without').val(webvisitorswithout * standardformfillwithout / 100);
            $('#number-of-sales-without').val(webvisitorswithout * standardformfillwithout / 100 * converstionofopportunitieswihtout / 100);
            $('#revenue-generated-without').val(averageordervaluewithout * numberofsaleswithout);
            $('#year-business-benefit-without').val(revenuegeneratedwithout * 12);
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $('#websitevisitors-with, #standard-form-fill-with, #conversion-of-opportunities-with, #number-of-sales-with, #average-order-value-with, #year-business-benefit-with, #revenue-generated-with').change(function() {
            var webvisitorswith = parseFloat($('#websitevisitors-with').val());
            var standardformfillwith = parseFloat($('#standard-form-fill-with').val());
            var converstionofopportunitieswihtout = parseFloat($('#conversion-of-opportunities-with').val());
            var numberofsaleswith = parseFloat($('#number-of-sales-with').val());
            var averageordervaluewith = parseFloat($('#average-order-value-with').val());
            var yearbusinessbenefitwith = parseFloat($('#year-business-benefit-with').val());
            var revenuegeneratedwith = parseFloat($('#revenue-generated-with').val());
    
            $('#number-of-form-fills-with, #total-opportunities-with').val(webvisitorswith * standardformfillwith / 100);
            $('#number-of-sales-with').val(webvisitorswith * standardformfillwith / 100 * converstionofopportunitieswihtout / 100);
            $('#revenue-generated-with').val(averageordervaluewith * numberofsaleswith);
            $('#year-business-benefit-with').val(revenuegeneratedwith * 12).toFixed(2);
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function myChangeFunction(websitevisitors-without) {
        var input2 = document.getElementById('websitevisitors-with');
        websitevisitors-with.value = websitevisitors-without.value;
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Isn't is easier to google "JavaScript round up"?

Comment: Please reduce your code to the neccessary bits to see you issue.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

Answer (score 1):

use `Math.ceil` to round up to the next bigger number
use `Math.floor` to round up to the next smaller number

eg

```
Math.ceil(0.3) // returns 1
Math.floor(0.3) //returns 0
```

Comment: Or Math.round() for the nearest int